# Passing array of objects from WCF to PHP - extracting the info

Tags: php, arrays, wcf, object

I have a method in a C# WCF service, which is responsible for extracting information from a database and then passing that information as an array of simple objects to a PHP site.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Lastname;
    public string Phone;
}
...
public Person[] GetPerson(){...}
```

Since I'm not really good with PHP, my problem is: How do I extract the information from the array at the PHP end of things? The most common error that i get is: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. I have tried many different things. The simple PHP code fragment:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:62532/Service1.svc?wsdl");

$ws = $client->GetPerson();
$wsr = $ws->GetPersonResult;

for($i = 0; $i < count($wsr); $i++)
{
echo $wsr[$i]->Id . "\n";
echo $wsr[$i]->Name . "\n";
echo $wsr[$i]->Lastname . "\n";
echo $wsr[$i]->Phone . "\n";
} 
?>
```

Does not work. When i call:

`print_r($wsr);`

to check the result of what the method returned i get:

```
stdClass Object 
( [Person] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[Id] => 1 [Name] => John [Lastname] => Abc [Phone] => 759687364 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
[Id] => 2 [Name] => Joe [Lastname] => Def [Phone] => 487512654 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( 
[Id] => 3 [Name] => Mike [Lastname] => Ghi [Phone] => 874587918 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( 
[Id] => 5 [Name] => Nick [Lastname] => Jkl [Phone] => 000000000) 
) 
)
```

So based on the result, the entire data exchange between WCF and PHP works fine, as those are the correct results, but i don't know how to easily (something along the lines of what I've tried above..) access them from within the array that is being returned.

I've searched quite a bit for a solution, but haven't found anything that would work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Ok, so the solution is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($wsr->Person); $i++)
{
echo $wsr->Person[$i]->Id . "\n";
echo $wsr->Person[$i]->Name . "\n";
echo $wsr->Person[$i]->Lastname . "\n";
echo $wsr->Person[$i]->Phone . "\n";
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$wsr->Person[$i]->Id`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, using a "classmap" would make your SOAP objects correspond to PHP objects, else it's useless to create a class "Person" and not map to it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

```
$server = new SoapClient(
    "http://localhost:62532/Service1.svc?wsdl", 
    array(
        'classmap' => array(
            'person' => "person"
        )
    )
);
```

What will result from this is the ability to receive a real ARRAY of PERSON object.

I've done it in reverse method by consuming a PHP webservice with c# and it works wonders...