# How to return database record from WCF

Tags: wcf, return

I have created WCF service i want to return database records from WCF service to client.

My client application retrieve that records display in web page. Client develop their application any platform like PHP or JAVA or .NET. They use my WCF service to get details.

How to return data from WCF service to Client application using XML or any other method?

Please give suggestion / code snippet on this to solve my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

If you deploy your WCF as `basicHttpBinding` will expose your WCF service as a legacy ASMX web service, so that old clients can work with the new service and will expose your data with SOAP protocol (XML based). You can also do something similar with `wsHttpBinding` (more advanced). I am suggesting basic, because you are going to consume it from PHP, Java & NET. Picking the more simple could work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <!—- Default binding for basicHttpBinding -->
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="myBindingConfiguration1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" />
                <binding name="myBindingConfiguration2" closeTimeout="00:02:00" />
                <binding closeTimeout="00:03:00" />  
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <!—- change to your namespace & contract details -->
            <service name="MyNamespace.myServiceType">
                <endpoint 
                 address="myAddress" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                 bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration1"
                 contract="MyContract"  />
                <endpoint 
                 address="myAddress2" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                 bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration2"
                 contract="MyContract" />
            </service>
        </services>
     </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

You can take more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx)

You can also configure the WCF to expose data as REST protocol (`WebHttpBinding`). That option limites WCF power. If you are going to consume your WCF from a javascript, you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach you can go with is exposing a **RESTful WCF** service using the WebHttpBinding which is designed for interoperable xml, json conversations. Then any client could issue an HTTP request to the endpoint and get the plain REST result. One downside of this technique is that you'll have to get familiar with WCF RESTful programming model which is described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx And you can find a comprehensive discussion on this topic here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/90716451-fd29-4917-a5ca-f7f3bcaa96c9

The second approach, that you'll probably like more because of its simplicity is using BasicHttpBinding service accessed through the **PHP buil-in SoapClient**. There's a good source illustrating .Net data type transmission to the PHP client. So you can use the same approach with your data: [Passing array of objects from WCF to PHP - extracting the info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763980/passing-array-of-objects-from-wcf-to-php-extracting-the-info) Just be careful and properly design your data contract class with [DataContract]/[DataMember] attributes.

And the following is for PHP WCF/BasicHttpIntegration starters: https://github.com/geersch/WcfServicesWithPhp5

**REST vs SOAP**
It's not that true that REST limits the WCF power, it actually does for some advanced WCF features mostly because of WebHttpBinding's limitations. But REST, in turn, is much more interoperable than any RPC protocols, like SOAP is. Plus you get lightweight JSON support in that case.
So your decision depends on your needs and your system's overall requirements/architecture. Agree, that if you just need to deliver a data-set like object to a few clients (especially if it's a local system, not published over internet) then, for the sake of simplicity, BasicHttpBinding/SOAP is the best for you.

One more thing to mention, that a lot of web services are either RESTful or being converted to REST. So does Microsoft too. It's the best way to deliver the data to the client's browser directly (JS takes the handle).